# I can’t get what Nietzsche exactly referring to by (the later is in no respect whatever an argument in favor of the former)?

Tags: truth, nietzsche

TRUTH”!—“The truth of Christianity was attested by the virtuous lives of the Christians, their firmness in suffering, their unshakable belief and above all by the spread and increase of the faith in spite of all calamities.”—That's how you talk even now. The more's the pity. Learn, then, that all this proves nothing either in favour of truth or against it; that truth must be demonstrated differently from conscientiousness, and that **the latter is in no respect whatever an argument in favour of the former**.

Comment: N is denying that "the virtuous lives of the Christians and their firmness in suffering" can support the “truth of Christianity".He says that  “The truth of Christianity" must be support by an "argument in favor of" (or against it).

Comment: Maybe your question can be more clear if you specify the source and what is the quotation and what is your text...

Comment: It’s from the daybreak, book 1 section 73, I just wanted to know which is not in favor of which

Comment: He's saying that conscientiousness — the dedicated application of will towards a goal — in no way demonstrates the 'truth' of something. To use a Blunt Example, Trump conscientiously and diligently repeating that he won the 2020 election in no way makes that assertion true. It merely proves that he is righteously and willfully committed to the cause. Martyrs prove the power of faith, not the truth of it.

Comment: Good answer, thanks